# No instance for (Num p) arising from a use of `+'

Tags: haskell, types, ghci

If I execute `myZipWith (+) (Point [1,2,3]) (Point [4,5,6])` from the GHCi terminal everything is OK, but if I try to execute it from a simple function, it gives me error.

Why is the execution directly from the terminal different even if the code is the same?

This is my code:

```
data Point p = Point [p]
deriving (Show)

wtf :: [p]
wtf = myZipWith (+) (Point [1,2,3]) (Point [4,5,6])

myZip :: Point p -> Point p -> [(p, p)]
myZip (Point []) _ = []
myZip _ (Point []) = []
myZip (Point (a:as)) (Point (b:bs)) = (a, b) : myZip (Point as) (Point bs)


myZipWith :: (p -> p -> p) -> Point p -> Point p -> [p]
myZipWith f (Point p1) (Point p2) = [ f (fst x) (snd x) | x <- (myZip (Point p1) (Point p2)) ]
```

Error code:

```
No instance for (Num p) arising from a use of `+'
      Possible fix:
        add (Num p) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            wtf :: forall p. [p]
    * In the first argument of `myZipWith', namely `(+)'
      In the expression:
        myZipWith (+) (Point [1, 2, 3]) (Point [4, 5, 6])
      In an equation for `wtf':
          wtf = myZipWith (+) (Point [1, 2, 3]) (Point [4, 5, 6])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined `wtf` to work for *any* type `p`, not just types that have `Num` instances. You need to include the constraint in your type annotation.

```
wtf :: Num p => [p]
wtf = myZipWith (+) (Point [1,2,3]) (Point [4,5,6])
```

This is the solution the suggested possible fix alludes to (i.e., "add[ing] `Num p` to the context of the type signature"). `myZip` and `myZipWith` don't need the annotation, because there is nothing `Num`-specific about them. Only the definition of `wtf`, which uses `(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`, requires the additional constraint.

If you had left off the type annotation, and simply wrote `wtf = myZipWith (+) (Point [1,2,3]) (Point [4,5,6])`, then Haskell would have inferred the type `Num a => [a]` for the list. Your explicit, overly general type prevented the inference from happening.

Comment: The last claim is not necessarily so, thanks to [the dreaded monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction). But of course it becomes so if you turn that restriction off.

Comment: Let's pretend it is off :)